# How to create a sub-page of sub-page?

Tags: php, menus, navigation

I am trying to organize my menus in my website. Since the structure is pretty complex I need some help with displaying the menus.

In the documentation of WP there is this example:

> Africa:
>   Cameroon
>   Lesotho
>   Swaziland
>   Togo
>   South Amerika
>   So the permalink() for Cameroon will be: http://example.com/africa/cameroon/

But in my structure I need something like this:

> http://example.com/africa/cameroon/street

In other words I have 2 parent pages A and B. B has 4 children(o,p,q,r(One menu should be shown for navigation around those children-menu1).O,p,q,r also have children. For example, o has a,y,x).So page o is child of B, thus one menu should be shown(menu2). BUT, o has children x,y,z so x,y,z should see both menu2, menu1 How to make the relation? I need to display different menu for all belongings of B but also extra menu for those who are children of the children of B. I give you example with displaying a menu for all pages of type B:

```
   <div class="localnavDiv">
    <ul class="localNav">



        <?php 
    if($post -> post_parent == $par_explore ->ID)
    {
        $items=wp_nav_menu
            ( array( 'theme_location' =>  'footer', 
                    'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 
                    'fallback_cb' => false ) );
        if (is_array($items) || is_object($items))
        {

            foreach($items as $item)
            { ?>
<li  class="liNav"  id="liRight" ><a class="active"   id="rightTitle"    href="http://localhost:81/DEMO/who-already-joined/"   onclick="myFunction()" ><?php echo $item ?></a></li>

<?php    
            }
        }
    }



        if($post -> post_parent == $par_develop ->ID)
    {
        $items=wp_nav_menu
            ( array( 'theme_location' =>  'develop', 
                    'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 
                    'fallback_cb' => false ) );
        if (is_array($items) || is_object($items))
        {

            foreach($items as $item)
            { ?>
<li  class="liNav"  id="liRight" ><a class="active"   id="rightTitle"    href="http://localhost:81/DEMO/who-already-joined/"   onclick="myFunction()" ><?php echo $item ?></a></li>

        foreach($explore_children as $exChild)
{*/



<?php    
            }
        }
    }

    // }


?>




</ul>
```

[image: Illustration of the exampkle]

I suppose, I can use category. So page B is parent of page O and  page x belongs to category (to replace O as a pernt).

I hope you understand a bit the problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I may be completely misunderstanding your question but I think you're trying to create something like the image below. Correct?

[image]

If that's the case you would create the menu structure either using the "Customize" or the "Menu" option in the "Appearance" menu in Wordpress.

[image]

The you simply arrange menu items the way you want them by dragging.

See below for the example I just created in a development site I'm working on.

[image]

Hope that helps :)